# Android Log Cat Error ContextResult::kFatalFailure

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error in Logcat when I run my app in the device or emulator:

```
[ERROR:context_group.cc(137)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: WebGL1 blacklisted
```

Why am I getting this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What's your device? I have that issue when using the emulator but it runs fine on my Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro.

From what I've found the issue is that software rendering is insufficient to handle webgl: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69236?focusedCommentId=413317&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel